# Spring @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/3 00-23 * * ?") : How to specify minutes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

https://crontab.cronhub.io/ states that expression "**0 0/3 00-23 * * ?**" will result in to

> Every 3 minutes, between 12:00 AM and 11:59 PM

However, I tried reading a lot of blogs but was incapable to discover how can I make an update to corn expression to do below, please guide.

> Every 3 minutes, between 12:15 AM and 11:45 PM

Comment: I think that what you want is not possible to achieve in a single cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression consists of five fields:

`<minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <command>`

At 12:00 p.m. (noon) every day:

`0 12 * * ?`

Every five minutes starting at 1 p.m. and ending at 1:55 p.m. and then starting at 6 p.m. and ending at 6:55 p.m., every day:

`0/5 13,18 * * ?`

Every minute starting at 1 p.m. and ending at 1:05 p.m., every day:

`0-5 13 * * ?`

For more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Thanks, @Fernando, your answer helps explain cron expression fundamentals. However, my need is a bit different, I want to be run every 3 minutes though skip between 12:15 AM and 11:45 PM.

Comment: For fixed range of hour or day this thread solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627256/cron-job-to-run-on-a-range-of-days-only-on-a-particular-day-of-week. but for very specific like yours maybe you'll need to do in code

Answer (score 0):

Make two cron entries.

One for the exact minutes (45,48,51,54,57) in hour 11 and one for the exact minutes (0,3,6,9,12,15) in hour 12.